# Java method available in Eclipse, but not in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use the `readAllBytes()` method from the `CipherInputStream` class in a library in Eclipse, however, when I use the library in Android, the method is not available. I have my source compatibility set to JAVA_1_8 for both the Android and Eclipse projects.

Why is the `readAllBytes()` method not available in Android?

Comment: Because it was not implemented in the Android SDK. There are many cases like this. An API available on the JDK doesn't mean it will be available on Android SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

readAllBytes was introduced with java10+, android isn't that far into it yet. Source compatibility is about which java language features are available. You can configure which JVM to use separately; install a JDK8 and point eclipse at that. Then getAllBytes should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the function you looking for:

```
    /**
         * Copies all available data from in to out without closing any stream.
         *
         * @return number of bytes copied
         */
        private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
        public static int copyAllBytes(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            int byteCount = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (true) {
                int read = in.read(buffer);
                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                byteCount += read;
            }
            return byteCount;
        }
```